# Gap appears in Longtable once copied into main document

Tags: longtable, two-column, books, gap

I created a `longtable` in a test file and made it work the way I want it. I then pasted that table in my main document, a two column book.
Although the `longtable` was looking good in my test document, once pasted in the book, a gap appeared on the first page of the table.
(**see screen captures 1, 2, and 3**: that's the whole `longtable` which should neatly fit on two pages, but now spreads over three pages, because of that gap).

After some tests to try and figure out what's going on, I ended up (as a test) pasting the exact same `longtable` after the first one (in the main book document), just to see what would happen. Lo and behold the second iteration of the table doesn't show the gap at all, and in fact looks as intended: a `longtable` spreading over two pages.
(**see screen capture 4 and 5**).

Why can't the first table work? Where is that gap coming from? How do I get rid of it?
Thank you.

Note: I'm pasting all the code (and only a portion of the table) from the test page, which is the same code that's used in the book, of course.

```
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
%\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
%\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % For shading in tables
%\usepackage{pdfcolmk} <==== not needed with xelatex
\usepackage{multirow}

%\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{caption} % To change way captions are labelled
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{nicefrac} % to write fractions
\usepackage{attrib} % For source of quotations
\usepackage{lettrine} % For NewThought formatting
\usepackage{array} % To define width of columns in long table
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer spacing in columns
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write Celsius, etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To create item lists

\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{textcomp} % For Numero symbol
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linguistics,edges]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titling}
%\usepackage{newpxtext} % Font for document instead of obsolete Palatino
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % Palatino clone

% To make TOC in two columns and List of Tables into one column.
\usepackage{multitoc}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@starttoc}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{toc}}{%
        \ifnum\multicolumntoc>1
        \begin{multicols}{\multicolumntoc}%
            \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \end{multicols}%
        \else
        \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \fi}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{lot}}{%
        \ifnum\multicolumnlot>1
        \begin{multicols}{\multicolumnlot}%
            \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \end{multicols}%
        \else
        \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \fi}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{lof}}{%
        \ifnum\multicolumnlof>1
        \begin{multicols}{\multicolumnlof}%
            \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \end{multicols}%
        \else
        \@multitoc@starttoc{#1}%
        \fi}{}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\multicolumnlot}{1}

% CREATING INDEX AND GLOSSARY %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\onecolumn
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[itemlayout=singlepar]{idxlayout}
%\makeindex[options=-s back-matter/index.ist]
%\twocolumn

%\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\indexsetup{othercode=\small}
\makeindex[program=makeindex,intoc=true,options={-s index.ist}]

\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks

\usepackage[toc,acronyms,automake,xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

% TO JUMP LINES IN TABLES see navy tables %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\mysplit}[1]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}   %% remove [t] if you need vertical centered things.
        #1
    \end{tabular}
}

% DEFINING CHAPTER AND SECTION COLORS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{green}{HTML}{3f8854}
\definecolor{runeg}{HTML}{3d857c}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{3d587e}
\definecolor{runeo}{HTML}{b6732b}
\definecolor{runer}{HTML}{af1824}

% HEADER AND FOOTER STYLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\headingfont \leftmark}
%\fancyhead[RE,LO]{Guides and tutorials}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\headingfont \thepage}
%\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\f@nch@head}{\rlap}{\color{runeg}\rlap}{}{}
\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{white}\hrule}{}{}
%\makeatother

% CHAPTER, SECTION, SUBSECTION STYLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Candara}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\color{runeg}\filcenter\fontsize{35}{35}\headingfont} % Size of Chapter1&Chapter
{\huge\MakeUppercase\headingfont{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{12pt}
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north) +
    (0pt,-117pt)$) {\includegraphics[width=14cm]{chapterHead_10cm}};}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{50mm}{42.5mm}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\color{runer}\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\color{runeo}\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\color{runeo}\headingfont}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\headingfont}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge\color{runeg}\headingfont} % tocloft <=====
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\Huge\color{runeg}\headingfont} % tocloft <=====
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries\color{runer}\headingfont} % tocloft <=====
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\color{runeo}\headingfont} % tocloft <===============
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\color{runeo}\headingfont} % tocloft <============
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\color{runeo}\headingfont} % tocloft <==========
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\color{runeo}\headingfont} % tocloft <===========
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\color{runeo}\headingfont} % tocloft <========
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecpagefont}{\color{runeo}\headingfont} % tocloft <=====

\begin{document}

{\small
    \onecolumn
    \begin{ThreePartTable}

        \begin{longtable}
            {
                >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6.6cm}
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6.6cm}
            }

            \caption{Prefered and restricted weapons of the non-humans}\label{AliensWeapons} \\
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Weapons}\\
            \cmidrule{2-3}
            \multirow{-2.5}*{Species} & Preferred & Restricted \\
            \midrule
            \endfirsthead

            \caption*{\autoref{AliensWeapons} (\textit{Continued})} \\
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Weapons}\\
            \cmidrule{2-3}
            \multirow{-2.5}*{Species} & Preferred & Restricted \\
            \midrule    
            \endhead
            qwertya & qwerty, erqgy, asdfghjj, assdf adfsf, sss ffff, fffsss cvbnmq. & wer hjkllod Ones never throw daggers or axes and rarely employ any type of missile weapon, slings being the only one used when they do. \\
            dadfg & that swords the are 234567rty' knives and chopper weapons like thin shaped, discs of. the convex rim with all around pizza (like sharpened cutters) & Else is little known of rim  use bronze \\
            vaaet & Light javelins, slender straight one-handed swords, occasionally light crossbows. They may also drop rocks or incendiaries from the air. Their rapier-like tail, which is usually poisoned, also functions as a weapon. & The furred jlehwn do not fight with their fists, nor do they employ bows, polearms, or one-handed weapons. A few have mastered the sling, however. \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{longtable}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
    \twocolumn
}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Long table cannot be split inside rows, only between them.  Changing from two colons to one colon and back always start new page. With your MWE is not possible to reproduce provided image. Repeating given table contents so many times that table is two and half page long not reproduce your problem. So the cause of your problem is not known to us.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I understand that the MWE doesn't reproduce the issue. However, it is the same code I have in my main document; I can't even recreate the issue myself, even after creating a new blank document and using the original two column book code in it. The problem I describe only seems to occur in the main document. Moreover, the issue is not that the document starts a new page (it doesn't), but it is that a gap appears in towards the beginning of the `longtable`.

Comment: what happens if you put `\clearpage` immediately before the longtable?

Comment: OMG it worked. Er ... why?

Comment: probably a bug, blame the longtable author.

Comment: actually not quite the same symptoms as the duplicate, but same issue and same fix